# How to remove undeclared dependencies workings from Maven build

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I'm working on a (web) project that makes use of a 'common' web component which implements much of base functionality of various projects (security, DB access etc). That common component (project pulls in as a maven dependency) brings with it a number of its own dependencies.

When I build my project with dependency:analyze, I get warnings about undeclared dependencies and unused declared dependencies in my pom.

That in itself isn't entirely unexpected, I've been tasked with tidying up dependencies in this project.

So there are a number of libraries that are inherited with the common code project (spring, hibernate....) that get highlighted by the plugin as undeclared dependencies.

Adding/removing these dependencies in my pom just seems to achieve nothing but swapping which list they appear in,  'unused declared' or 'used undeclared' section of the output.

What is the best practice approach to this situation in maven?

Given my project is dependent on the common project (which is unlikely to get updated) should I:

- remove them from my pom and rely on the common project bringing them in
- add explicitly to my project pom, exclude from the common project
- add them to my pom with specific scope (runtime/provided) with 'ignoreNonCompile' flag
- something else

Comment: I wouldn't care much about "dependency:analyze" output. Just make sure that everything declared as dependency in common component is actually used. Declaring single version for used artifacts in parent POM's "<dependencyManagement>" section is also more important than warnings from "dependency:analyze.

Comment: I have been migrating hard wired module dependency version into the dependencyManagement section of parent pom, that's helping line things up.
@user158037
To give this some context, this is around OWASP work. To remove unused components (in which we included our dependencies as needing work).